# Add inline styling to link in CK Editor 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I would like to add a inline styling color to a link when it is created by the user in CK editor. Is this possible?

Regards, Andreas

Comment: I don't think it is possible - but it's probably better a question for their [support](http://ckeditor.com/support)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ..

Create a separate style in new css file and then assign path in ContentCSS.

info : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss

Comment: Caveat: contentsCss is ignored for inline editors and in full page mode. In these cases just apply css to the page in the usual way and the editor will see it.